# Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class

Tags: android, apk

I am creating an application for android, at first i used one library project to include Panel functionality in the application and it worked fine. Later i found that my .apk file included my unused images and xml file of library project which increased the size of my application, so i decided to implement the panel functionality on my own. When i ran the application after making the changes i am getting the error `09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.widgets.application/com.widgets.application.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.widgets.application.utils.Panel`

I am uploading my project here, please help me get rid of this problem

http://www.mediafire.com/?m10u0y5cenqnb1u

The log cat is as below

```
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.widgets.application/com.widgets.application.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.widgets.application.utils.Panel
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.widgets.application.utils.Panel
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at com.widgets.application.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     ... 11 more
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     ... 22 more
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #14: The content attribute is required and must refer to a valid child.
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at com.widgets.application.utils.Panel.<init>(Panel.java:116)
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     ... 25 more
```

**EDIT: Panel.java**;

```
public class Panel extends LinearLayout {

private static final String TAG = "Panel";

/**
 * Callback invoked when the panel is opened/closed.
 */
public static interface OnPanelListener {
    /**
     * Invoked when the panel becomes fully closed.
     */
    public void onPanelClosed(Panel panel);

    /**
     * Invoked when the panel becomes fully opened.
     */
    public void onPanelOpened(Panel panel);
}

private boolean mIsShrinking;
private int mPosition;
private int mDuration;
private boolean mLinearFlying;
private int mHandleId;
private int mContentId;
private View mHandle;
private View mContent;
private Drawable mOpenedHandle;
private Drawable mClosedHandle;
private float mTrackX;
private float mTrackY;
private float mVelocity;

private OnPanelListener panelListener;

public static final int TOP = 0;
public static final int BOTTOM = 1;
public static final int LEFT = 2;
public static final int RIGHT = 3;

private enum State {
    ABOUT_TO_ANIMATE, ANIMATING, READY, TRACKING, FLYING,
};

private State mState;
private Interpolator mInterpolator;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private int mContentHeight;
private int mContentWidth;
private int mOrientation;
private float mWeight;
private PanelOnGestureListener mGestureListener;
private boolean mBringToFront;

public Panel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Panel);
    mDuration = a.getInteger(R.styleable.Panel_animationDuration, 750); // duration
                                                                        // defaults
                                                                        // to
                                                                        // 750
                                                                        // ms
    mPosition = a.getInteger(R.styleable.Panel_position, BOTTOM); // position
                                                                    // defaults
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // BOTTOM
    mLinearFlying = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.Panel_linearFlying, false); // linearFlying
                                                                            // defaults
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // false
    mWeight = a.getFraction(R.styleable.Panel_weight, 0, 1, 0.0f); // weight
                                                                    // defaults
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // 0.0
    if (mWeight < 0 || mWeight > 1) {
        mWeight = 0.0f;
        Log.w(TAG, a.getPositionDescription()
                + ": weight must be > 0 and <= 1");
    }
    mOpenedHandle = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.Panel_openedHandle);
    mClosedHandle = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.Panel_closedHandle);

    RuntimeException e = null;
    mHandleId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Panel_handle, 0);
    if (mHandleId == 0) {
        e = new IllegalArgumentException(
                a.getPositionDescription()
                        + ": The handle attribute is required and must refer to a valid child.");
    }
    mContentId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Panel_content, 0);
    if (mContentId == 0) {
        e = new IllegalArgumentException(
                a.getPositionDescription()
                        + ": The content attribute is required and must refer to a valid child.");
    }
    a.recycle();

    if (e != null) {
        throw e;
    }
    mOrientation = (mPosition == TOP || mPosition == BOTTOM) ? VERTICAL
            : HORIZONTAL;
    setOrientation(mOrientation);
    mState = State.READY;
    mGestureListener = new PanelOnGestureListener();
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mGestureListener);
    mGestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);

    // i DON'T really know why i need this...
    setBaselineAligned(false);
}

/**
 * Sets the listener that receives a notification when the panel becomes
 * open/close.
 * 
 * @param onPanelListener
 *            The listener to be notified when the panel is opened/closed.
 */
public void setOnPanelListener(OnPanelListener onPanelListener) {
    panelListener = onPanelListener;
}

/**
 * Gets Panel's mHandle
 * 
 * @return Panel's mHandle
 */
public View getHandle() {
    return mHandle;
}

/**
 * Gets Panel's mContent
 * 
 * @return Panel's mContent
 */
public View getContent() {
    return mContent;
}

/**
 * Sets the acceleration curve for panel's animation.
 * 
 * @param i
 *            The interpolator which defines the acceleration curve
 */
public void setInterpolator(Interpolator i) {
    mInterpolator = i;
}

/**
 * Set the opened state of Panel.
 * 
 * @param open
 *            True if Panel is to be opened, false if Panel is to be closed.
 * @param animate
 *            True if use animation, false otherwise.
 * 
 * @return True if operation was performed, false otherwise.
 * 
 */
public boolean setOpen(boolean open, boolean animate) {
    if (mState == State.READY && isOpen() ^ open) {
        mIsShrinking = !open;
        if (animate) {
            mState = State.ABOUT_TO_ANIMATE;
            if (!mIsShrinking) {
                // this could make flicker so we test mState in
                // dispatchDraw()
                // to see if is equal to ABOUT_TO_ANIMATE
                mContent.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }
            post(startAnimation);
        } else {
            mContent.setVisibility(open ? VISIBLE : GONE);
            postProcess();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns the opened status for Panel.
 * 
 * @return True if Panel is opened, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isOpen() {
    return mContent.getVisibility() == VISIBLE;
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    mHandle = findViewById(mHandleId);
    if (mHandle == null) {
        String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(mHandleId);
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Your Panel must have a child View whose id attribute is 'R.id."
                        + name + "'");
    }
    mHandle.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    mHandle.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    mContent = findViewById(mContentId);
    if (mContent == null) {
        String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(mHandleId);
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Your Panel must have a child View whose id attribute is 'R.id."
                        + name + "'");
    }

    // reposition children
    removeView(mHandle);
    removeView(mContent);
    if (mPosition == TOP || mPosition == LEFT) {
        addView(mContent);
        addView(mHandle);
    } else {
        addView(mHandle);
        addView(mContent);
    }

    if (mClosedHandle != null) {
        mHandle.setBackgroundDrawable(mClosedHandle);
    }
    mContent.setClickable(true);
    mContent.setVisibility(GONE);
    if (mWeight > 0) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mContent.getLayoutParams();
        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
            params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        } else {
            params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        }
        mContent.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    ViewParent parent = getParent();
    if (parent != null && parent instanceof FrameLayout) {
        mBringToFront = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (mWeight > 0 && mContent.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
        View parent = (View) getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        (int) (parent.getHeight() * mWeight),
                        MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            } else {
                widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        (int) (parent.getWidth() * mWeight),
                        MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            }
        }
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    mContentWidth = mContent.getWidth();
    mContentHeight = mContent.getHeight();
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(getId());
    // Log.d(TAG, name + " ispatchDraw " + mState);
    // this is why 'mState' was added:
    // avoid flicker before animation start
    if (mState == State.ABOUT_TO_ANIMATE && !mIsShrinking) {
        int delta = mOrientation == VERTICAL ? mContentHeight
                : mContentWidth;
        if (mPosition == LEFT || mPosition == TOP) {
            delta = -delta;
        }
        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
            canvas.translate(0, delta);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(delta, 0);
        }
    }
    if (mState == State.TRACKING || mState == State.FLYING) {
        canvas.translate(mTrackX, mTrackY);
    }
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}

private float ensureRange(float v, int min, int max) {
    v = Math.max(v, min);
    v = Math.min(v, max);
    return v;
}

OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    int initX;
    int initY;
    boolean setInitialPosition;

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mState == State.ANIMATING) {
            // we are animating
            return false;
        }
        // Log.d(TAG, "state: " + mState + " x: " + event.getX() + " y: " +
        // event.getY());
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (mBringToFront) {
                bringToFront();
            }
            initX = 0;
            initY = 0;
            if (mContent.getVisibility() == GONE) {
                // since we may not know content dimensions we use factors
                // here
                if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
                    initY = mPosition == TOP ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                    initX = mPosition == LEFT ? -1 : 1;
                }
            }
            setInitialPosition = true;
        } else {
            if (setInitialPosition) {
                // now we know content dimensions, so we multiply factors...
                initX *= mContentWidth;
                initY *= mContentHeight;
                // ... and set initial panel's position
                mGestureListener.setScroll(initX, initY);
                setInitialPosition = false;
                // for offsetLocation we have to invert values
                initX = -initX;
                initY = -initY;
            }
            // offset every ACTION_MOVE & ACTION_UP event
            event.offsetLocation(initX, initY);
        }
        if (!mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // tup up after scrolling
                post(startAnimation);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mBringToFront) {
            bringToFront();
        }
        if (initChange()) {
            post(startAnimation);
        }
    }
};

public boolean initChange() {
    if (mState != State.READY) {
        // we are animating or just about to animate
        return false;
    }
    mState = State.ABOUT_TO_ANIMATE;
    mIsShrinking = mContent.getVisibility() == VISIBLE;
    if (!mIsShrinking) {
        // this could make flicker so we test mState in dispatchDraw()
        // to see if is equal to ABOUT_TO_ANIMATE
        mContent.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
    return true;
}

Runnable startAnimation = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // this is why we post this Runnable couple of lines above:
        // now its save to use mContent.getHeight() && mContent.getWidth()
        TranslateAnimation animation;
        int fromXDelta = 0, toXDelta = 0, fromYDelta = 0, toYDelta = 0;
        if (mState == State.FLYING) {
            mIsShrinking = (mPosition == TOP || mPosition == LEFT)
                    ^ (mVelocity > 0);
        }
        int calculatedDuration;
        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
            int height = mContentHeight;
            if (!mIsShrinking) {
                fromYDelta = mPosition == TOP ? -height : height;
            } else {
                toYDelta = mPosition == TOP ? -height : height;
            }
            if (mState == State.TRACKING) {
                if (Math.abs(mTrackY - fromYDelta) < Math.abs(mTrackY
                        - toYDelta)) {
                    mIsShrinking = !mIsShrinking;
                    toYDelta = fromYDelta;
                }
                fromYDelta = (int) mTrackY;
            } else if (mState == State.FLYING) {
                fromYDelta = (int) mTrackY;
            }
            // for FLYING events we calculate animation duration based on
            // flying velocity
            // also for very high velocity make sure duration >= 20 ms
            if (mState == State.FLYING && mLinearFlying) {
                calculatedDuration = (int) (1000 * Math
                        .abs((toYDelta - fromYDelta) / mVelocity));
                calculatedDuration = Math.max(calculatedDuration, 20);
            } else {
                calculatedDuration = mDuration
                        * Math.abs(toYDelta - fromYDelta) / mContentHeight;
            }
        } else {
            int width = mContentWidth;
            if (!mIsShrinking) {
                fromXDelta = mPosition == LEFT ? -width : width;
            } else {
                toXDelta = mPosition == LEFT ? -width : width;
            }
            if (mState == State.TRACKING) {
                if (Math.abs(mTrackX - fromXDelta) < Math.abs(mTrackX
                        - toXDelta)) {
                    mIsShrinking = !mIsShrinking;
                    toXDelta = fromXDelta;
                }
                fromXDelta = (int) mTrackX;
            } else if (mState == State.FLYING) {
                fromXDelta = (int) mTrackX;
            }
            // for FLYING events we calculate animation duration based on
            // flying velocity
            // also for very high velocity make sure duration >= 20 ms
            if (mState == State.FLYING && mLinearFlying) {
                calculatedDuration = (int) (1000 * Math
                        .abs((toXDelta - fromXDelta) / mVelocity));
                calculatedDuration = Math.max(calculatedDuration, 20);
            } else {
                calculatedDuration = mDuration
                        * Math.abs(toXDelta - fromXDelta) / mContentWidth;
            }
        }

        mTrackX = mTrackY = 0;
        if (calculatedDuration == 0) {
            mState = State.READY;
            if (mIsShrinking) {
                mContent.setVisibility(GONE);
            }
            postProcess();
            return;
        }

        animation = new TranslateAnimation(fromXDelta, toXDelta,
                fromYDelta, toYDelta);
        animation.setDuration(calculatedDuration);
        animation.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
        if (mState == State.FLYING && mLinearFlying) {
            animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        } else if (mInterpolator != null) {
            animation.setInterpolator(mInterpolator);
        }
        startAnimation(animation);
    }
};

private AnimationListener animationListener = new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        mState = State.READY;
        if (mIsShrinking) {
            mContent.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        postProcess();
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        mState = State.ANIMATING;
    }
};

private void postProcess() {
    if (mIsShrinking && mClosedHandle != null) {
        mHandle.setBackgroundDrawable(mClosedHandle);
    } else if (!mIsShrinking && mOpenedHandle != null) {
        mHandle.setBackgroundDrawable(mOpenedHandle);
    }
    // invoke listener if any
    if (panelListener != null) {
        if (mIsShrinking) {
            panelListener.onPanelClosed(Panel.this);
        } else {
            panelListener.onPanelOpened(Panel.this);
        }
    }
}

class PanelOnGestureListener implements OnGestureListener {
    float scrollY;
    float scrollX;

    public void setScroll(int initScrollX, int initScrollY) {
        scrollX = initScrollX;
        scrollY = initScrollY;
    }

    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        scrollX = scrollY = 0;
        initChange();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        mState = State.FLYING;
        mVelocity = mOrientation == VERTICAL ? velocityY : velocityX;
        post(startAnimation);
        return true;
    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // not used
    }

    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        mState = State.TRACKING;
        float tmpY = 0, tmpX = 0;
        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
            scrollY -= distanceY;
            if (mPosition == TOP) {
                tmpY = ensureRange(scrollY, -mContentHeight, 0);
            } else {
                tmpY = ensureRange(scrollY, 0, mContentHeight);
            }
        } else {
            scrollX -= distanceX;
            if (mPosition == LEFT) {
                tmpX = ensureRange(scrollX, -mContentWidth, 0);
            } else {
                tmpX = ensureRange(scrollX, 0, mContentWidth);
            }
        }
        if (tmpX != mTrackX || tmpY != mTrackY) {
            mTrackX = tmpX;
            mTrackY = tmpY;
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // not used
    }

    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // not used
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: suggestion : use http://pastie.org/pastes/new instead of mediafire...

Comment: The error is more likely to be in your class constructors.  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #14: The content attribute is required and must refer to a valid child.
09-28 00:01:00.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1462):     at com.widgets.application.utils.Panel.<init>(Panel.java:116)

Comment: @Simon i have uploaded my project, can you please check it?

Comment: Just edit your post to show the constructors for your Panel class.  No-one is going to download an entire project from Mediafire just to debug it.

Comment: @Simon see my edit i have posted the panel class

Comment: I only needed the constructors!  Anyway, where is your styleable defined?

Comment: @Simon Stylable are in attrs.xml file  in values folder. can u download and check the project? its just 674 kb...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configured it finally. Just one line of code was messing up the whole application. Just changed that line and application was up and running. Posting the solution so it may help someone in future. This line should be changed in layout file

`xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`